# Does the overall closing questions policy too procrastinating?

Tags: discussion, closing, close-reasons, closed-questions

I find that when asking e.g. slightly cunning DEs, some corps will make those questions close quite quickly, but reopening those questions are often very difficult, influence greatly the image of MSE that welcome maths not only in scholar uses.

Comment: Could you link some examples, please? I am not sure what you mean specifically. What is true is that real-world inspired questions sometimes have a hard time.

Comment: If the questions were not good, then it is a good thing that they are closed quickly and not reopened.  Were the questions good?

Answer (score 3):

I read this question as pointing to the asymmetry that a question can get closed very quickly but might take a lot more time to get reopened after being improved. Provided that both closure and reopening were appropriate, I think that is a feature not a bug. If questions get reopened immediately, askers have less incentive to get things right the first time, which is something I think we all should aspire to.

Comment: I note that OP made no mention of improving the questions.

Comment: @GerryMyerson What else could be "very difficult" in the process?

Comment: Getting the attention of a sufficient number of voters to reopen could be difficult. Once a question is off the front page, it takes some effort just to realize that it has been closed.